# How to calculate a**b when a and b both are very large(in order of 10**10 to 10**18)?

Tags: python

i need to calculate `((2**a)*(a))%1000000007` where a is in order of 10^10. as much as i know python can handle int less than 2^1400. then is there any way to calculate this? or any mathematical rule to solve it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalences

Comment: See the two duplicates; one on the general approach to these problems (large numbers with a remainder), the other pointing to the `math.pow()` function, which *already* uses those same techniques to keep the results manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets really easy since python's `math.pow` has an optional argument for modulo.

```
from math import pow
(pow(2, a, 1000000007)*a)%1000000007
```

This let's you not do the `2**a` to all the digits and just return the modulo.